# Between the two string to use with the php xml parser

Tags: php, xml, string

```
<title><![CDATA[ hello
    ]]></title>
          <link>http://www.google.com</link>
          <description><img class="img" src="http://google.com/a.jpg" alt="" /></a>]]></description>
    <title><![CDATA[ good
    ]]></title>
          <link>http://www.google.com</link>
          <description><img class="img" src="http://google.com/b.jpg" /></a>]]></description>
    <title><![CDATA[ world
    ]]></title>
          <link>http://www.google.com</link>
          <description><img class="img" src="http://google.com/c.jpg" alt="" /></a>]]></description>
```

I want to copy the text between **`<![CDATA[`** and **`]]>`** then paste them into **alt** attribute.

The example above should be;

```
<title><![CDATA[ hello
    ]]></title>
          <link>http://www.google.com</link>
          <description><img class="img" src="http://google.com/a.jpg" alt="hello" /></a>]]></description>
    <title><![CDATA[ good
    ]]></title>
          <link>http://www.google.com</link>
          <description><img class="img" src="http://google.com/b.jpg" /></a>]]></description>
    <title><![CDATA[ world
    ]]></title>
          <link>http://www.google.com</link>
          <description><img class="img" src="http://google.com/c.jpg" alt="world" /></a>]]></description>
```

Is it possible?
How to do it would be reasonable, if possible?

Comment: your xml is broken: http://www.xmlvalidation.com

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `htmlspecialchars` as it was just for test purposes. 
As @michi says you need valid xml. Each group should be in a block container For Example `<example>stuff </example>` as below

**test data**

```
<?php
$testdata = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<test>

<example>
<title><![CDATA[ example 1]]></title>
          <link>http://www.example1.com</link>
          <description><![CDATA[ <img class="img" src="http://google.com/a.jpg" alt="" /></a>]]></description>
</example>

<example>
    <title><![CDATA[ example 2]]></title>
          <link>http://www.example2.com</link>
          <description><![CDATA[ <img class="img" src="http://google.com/b.jpg" /></a>]]></description>

       </example>

       <example>   
    <title><![CDATA[ example 3 ]]></title>
          <link>http://www.example3.com</link>
          <description><![CDATA[ <img class="img" src="http://google.com/c.jpg" alt="" /></a>]]></description>

          </example>


</test>
XML;
```

**output code**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($testdata, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach ($xml->example as $v){ 

 // find and replace alt
 $img = str_replace( 'alt=""','', $v->description);
 $img = str_replace( '<img','<img alt="'.$v->title.'"', $img);


echo htmlspecialchars(
'
<example>  
    <title><![CDATA[ '.$v->title.']]></title>
    <link>'.$v->link.'</link>
    <description><![CDATA[ '.$img.'</a>]]></description>
</example>
');
 }
?>
```